# Polymorphic deserialization in Jackson without annotations

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson, deserialization

I have a `CloudEvent<T>` class that uses polymorphic deserialization using Jackson (2.9.0 - last version) like this:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class CloudEvent<T> {

    @NonNull
    private String eventType;

    @JsonTypeInfo(
            use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
            include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXTERNAL_PROPERTY,
            property = "eventType",
            defaultImpl = Void.class)
    @JsonSubTypes({
            @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = MyEvent1.class, name = "event-1"),
            @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = MyEvent2.class, name = "event-2")
    })
    private T data;
}
```

And then deserialized with:

```
String cloudEventJson1 = "{\"eventType\":\"event-1\",\"data\":{\"id\":\"123\",\"details\":\"detail1\"}}";

CloudEvent deserializedEvent1 = objectMapper.readValue(cloudEventJson1, CloudEvent.class);   //without subtypes
```

All this works fine.
But because some limitations, I can not use annotations on the CloudEvent class (provided by external dependency).

So I configured the ObjectMapper like this:

```
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.registerSubtypes(new NamedType(MyEvent1.class, "event-1"));
    objectMapper.registerSubtypes(new NamedType(MyEvent2.class, "event-2"));

    TypeResolverBuilder  typeResolverBuilder = new ObjectMapper.DefaultTypeResolverBuilder(ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.OBJECT_AND_NON_CONCRETE)
      .init(JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, null)   //CLASS works
      .inclusion(JsonTypeInfo.As.EXTERNAL_PROPERTY)
      .typeProperty("eventType")
      .typeIdVisibility(true)
//    .defaultImpl(Void.class);
    objectMapper.setDefaultTyping(typeResolverBuilder);
```

But deserializing with same method as above does not work. It is reading the `eventType` but it is not managing to match to the registered subtype. 
I can not use generics or TypeReferance in the deserialization because I need to use `spring-integration` for reading the events which only accepts main class; the pattern matching being done manually after deserialization.

Exception:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidTypeIdException: Could not resolve type id 'event-1' as a subtype of [simple type, class java.lang.Object]: known type ids = [] (for POJO property 'data')
 at [Source: (String)"{"eventType":"event-1","data":{"id":"123","details":"detail1"}}"; line: 1, column: 271]
```

Also this is configuring the ObjectMapper for all input classes. Is it possible to connect this `typeResolverBuilder` and `subtypes` to the `CloudEvent.class` (like the annotation way does it).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can still rely on annotations even if you cannot modify your class. Jackson supports a feature called *mix-ins*: you can think of it as kind of aspect-oriented way of adding more annotations during runtime, to augment statically defined ones.

First define an interface as follows:

```java
public interface CloudEventMixIn<T> {

     @JsonTypeInfo(
            use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
            include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXTERNAL_PROPERTY,
            property = "eventType",
            defaultImpl = Void.class)
    @JsonSubTypes({
            @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = MyEvent1.class, name = "event-1"),
            @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = MyEvent2.class, name = "event-2")
    })
    public T getData();
}
```

Then configure `ObjectMapper` to use the defined interface as a mix-in for actual class/interface:

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.addMixIn(CloudEvent.class, CloudEventMixIn.class);
```

From the [`addMixIn(Class<?> target, Class<?> mixinSource)`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#addMixIn-java.lang.Class-java.lang.Class-) method documentation:

> Method to use for adding mix-in annotations to use for augmenting specified class or interface. All annotations from `mixinSource` are taken to override annotations that `target` (or its supertypes) has.

Comment: works very well and it's very convenient. thanks!  One thing to add is that if you have issue by Jackson adding the `type` field twice, just add this in the mixin to ignore the manually set type: `@JsonTypeId  String getType();`